# Tranformación de XML usando XSL (SublimeText3)

Tags: xml, macos, sublimetext3, xsl, xslt

Sé que existen herramientas externas, pero me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de transformar un XML con un XSL por SublimeText3, a través de algún snippet o package o algún otro modo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hay un snippet (XSLT Snippets) pero poca cosa más.

Yo dejo "linkado" el xml con xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="tu_archivo.xsl"?>
```

Y después lo abro el xml con Firefox (Chrome no tiene soporte).
El mismo navegador reproduce el xml transformado y ademas te marca los errores

Comment: Gracias por su ayuda! Utilizaré el "link" que ha mencionado.